# Converting XLR to old 5 pin amplifier inputs?

Tags: cable, pa

Cables into the back of our old church PA amp are male 5-pin plugs. About 1cm across with 5 round pins.

I know these can convert to regular XLR because that's how they are wired buti cannot access the wiring to see how.

Confusingly, these same 5 pin plugs seem to be used for audio as an XLR variant, and for lighting rigs. So it's making it harder to tell what adapter will or won't work... I want to connect a regular XLR from a microphone into a spare input so what requirements does an adapter have for this... Or should any 5-3 pin adapter be fine in practice?

[image]

Comment: Are the 5-pin XLR or DIN? If they're XLR, they *may* be part of an old headset system. Your safest course of action, presuming schematics aren't available, is to dismantle either one of the existing plugs or the amp itself. Guessing is never a good idea. Replacing the old sockets to take modern plugs is also an option.

Comment: The old sockets seem like DIN, which are the same as used in MIDI connections. They come in various configurations, with the pins at different sweeps. The most usual is all 5 pins covering 180degrees. The centre pin is earth or screen. Usually the two on one side are L&R in, oter two are L&R out. So here, there's probably only two (or even just one) pin connected, since it's an input. It won't take much to solder the screen onto the centre pin, and use a lead that you know is wired for the mic end. Touch the centre wire onto each pin, while someone uses the mic. At some point, something will..

Comment: ..work. That's the pin! There may be a problem with impedance matching, though. A lot of vocal mics are low impedance, and I guess the input was made for high impedance. This may not be a problem - just need to adjust the vol. control - which should have been half up durring the test.You *may* be able to buy an adapter - DIN-XLR - but with 5 pins on one and 3 on the other, the chances of it being wired correct pins too correct pins are pretty slender. That's why I would (and have many times) used the above method.

Comment: Managed to get a photo to upload. The amp has 6 inputs all as female 5pin.

Comment: Are these actually mic or line-level inputs?  I remember the 5-pin DIN being widely used on tape recorders for line in and line out (wired as described by Tim).

Comment: Good question. I might have to look up the amp but it's like a hifi amp with 6 inputs of this style. I know we plug in a microphone and it works. I also know if I take the XLR output from a DI box this works too, in both cases the input level is at a sensible level to get reasonable volume.

Comment: I can't believe those plug/sockets were used for lighting. They won't take a huge amount of current. The plug is called '180degree 5 pin DIN'.

Comment: Sorry for extended comments but I bought a converter just to see: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0013XWB14. It looks identical but is about 2mm larger than the sockets! What might our sockets be, or where can I find out?

Comment: @MrBoy: that adapter has a 5-pin XLR connector, not a DIN one. DIN is smaller. You need something [like this](https://www.amazon.com/CablesOnline-Dual-XLR-Professional-Premium-BO-906/dp/B00EMHWYQK). For that price, I'd solder one myself, but I happen to have some DIN plugs lying around.